# How can I enable a button on a react app using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

For a project I am trying to login to my local grocery store and automate some interactions without using services similar to Selenium.
Using chrome dev tools and safari dev tools I have been able to login since the login button is always enabled.

```
document.getElementById('label-email').value = 'ihaveanemail@email.com';
document.getElementById('label-password').value = 'password';
document.getElementById('btnSignIn').click();
```

When I navigate to my account settings a button is disabled and wont let me submit.

I have tried removing/ changing the disabled attribute on the button but it only changes the color of the button from light grey to a dark grey. (the button is usually red when enabled).  I made a custom event and changed the isTrusted attribute of the request but it doesnt work either.

```
var labelEmailInput = document.getElementById('label-email')
var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
clickEvent.isTrusted = true;
labelEmailInput.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

I have searched through the event listeners and tried to manually trigger the events related to the button and its parents. I toggled the events to observe any changes to see if I could complete the process.

The button gets enabled when I click on the inputs and the length requirment is met. When the button is enabled I also see a response in the network tab that sends an image of a green check for a text element to use in its confirmation message that the length requirement is met. I believe they are using some form of client side detection.

This is the button

```
<button type="button" disabled="" class="btn uca-button btn-secondary core-btn btn-sm">Save</button>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: have you tried `getElementById().focus()` on both elements before clicking the submit?

Comment: your question is not clear enough.. but what i see is that  u need to remove disabled attribute from button.. if thats the case.. then you can do `document.querySelector('button.uca-button').disabled = true;` or `document.querySelector('button.uca-button').removeAttribute('disabled');`...